# Ask IntelliJ IDEA to open one of my library sources for a given value / class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is it possible without having to scribble into a randomly chosen .scala document, to ask IntelliJ IDEA to open the source for a given class name. For example, say I want to see the source of `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop` (scala-compiler.jar is in my project dependencies). I am looking for like a dialogue that let's me enter `ILoop`, then suggest the full class name and open the source code.

The workaround is to create an empty document, type `ILoop`, confirm the auto import, and then go into the source using Cmd-B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ctrl+N` shortcut (Go To Class) and check "Include non-project classes".

Comment: Great! BTW, it's Cmd-N on OS X.